# Cypress IF-ELSE on Selected option

Tags: select, cypress

I would like to check that if the "France" option is selected in field 1, then I select the "Euro" option in field 2.

And if in field 1 the option "USA" is selected, then in field 2 I select the option "Dollars".

[image]

```
cy.get('State').then(($btn) => {
          // assert on the text
          if ($btn.text().to.equal('France')) {
               cy.get('#vs3__combobox > .vs__actions').click() //Expands
               cy.get('#dialog-2').contains('Euro').click() //Selects
          } else {
               cy.get('#vs3__combobox > .vs__actions').click() //Expands
               cy.get('#dialog-2').contains('Dollars').click() //Selects
          }
  })
```

But I can't get it right and I'm new to Cypress / Javascript.

Thank you

Comment: What error message are you getting when running the provided code?

Comment: I have this error : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I'd do it is much simpler, using `invoke('val')` to get the current value of the State `<select>` element.

It will be either "FR" or "US" or nothing, based on the `value="FR"` attributes of the options.

```js
cy.get('select#State')
  .invoke('val')          // what is selected
  .then(selected => {
    if (selected === 'FR') {
      // do French stuff
    }
    if (selected === 'FR') {
      // do USA stuff
    }
    if (selected === '') {
      // default selected is the first option
      cy.log('Nothing is selected')
    }
  })
```

Getting the `text()` of the `<select>` doesn't tell you what it's currently selected value is.

For reference: [Cypress examples (v13.3.3) - Selected value](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/selected-value.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is formed incorrectly. The `.to.equal()` function is a Chai chained assertion, and requires being chained off of a `Chai.expect()` or `Chai.should()` function like so:

```js
expect($btn.text()).to.equal('France');
```

However, doing so would run the Chai assertion, and not return a Boolean value for the if/else statement to evaluate. Instead, your statement can be in the traditional JS `$btn.text() ==` format.

```js
if ($btn.text() == 'France') {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: When I use this If-else statement, only the Else part is executed. So I did cy.log($btn.text()) and got this in the log "Select an optionFranceUSA"

Comment: After selecting an option, does the text value of the `input` field change? What about just the `value` property?

Comment: The only change is in the else and it always selects the "Dollars" option. And when I put "Euro" in the Else, it selects that option this time. 

When I run this before the if-else, "cy.get('[data-test="State"]').select("France")", it does select "France" but it still doesn't take into account the IF

Comment: Right - does it change when you manually select the change? Right now, how you're finding the `input` element, it is yielding all options as the text. So I'm trying to see if that value changes, or if the actual `value` property changes.

Comment: When I manually select an option, it is taken into account, but the actual value property does not change.